# Does the copper normalize?

Tags: quantum-chemistry

I am reading Concepts of Elemental Particle Physics.  In it, it describes what happens when a high energy muon is shot into a copper rod.  An electron is is knocked out of its orbit and and photons are shot out at all angles.  Pretty easy to understand.  My question is this...  We have an atom that is now missing an electron.  Does the copper normalize in that the electron finds a home in another atom and what happens to the ionic atom?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand it, metals have free electrons.  In a classical sense they're free to just rove around anywhere they 'want' to in a sea of electrons.  In a quantum sense they're delocalized -- with the same effect on a macro level as a mostly-classical sea of electrons.

If you shoot a muon into a metal then one of three things is going to happen: it's going to just start acting like one of those free electrons, at least until it decays, or it's going to find some localized spot in the crystal lattice where it's happy, but it's not going to be bound to any one atom, or it's going to displace an electron from an inner shell of one of the metal atoms, at which point that displaced electron will end up in the sea of electrons.

So, by and large, that copper rod is just going to act like it has one excess electron.  If you want to know what happens to the rod as a whole, ask whether a metal rod with a negative charge on it is ionized.

I don't believe that the concept of "ionization" applies in this case, though, because that sea of electrons is shared by all the atoms in the metal.  *All* the atoms in the rod will probably feel a *slight* excess of electrons, but I'm pretty sure that none of them will be ionized in the sense of definitely missing an electron.

Comment: Makes a lot of sense... Thank you